# Magento 1.5 override Catalog block

Tags: magento, overriding, codeblocks

I'm tryin to override Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php .

Assume that my module named Abc.

Here is my app/etc/modules/Abc_Catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abc_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Abc_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here is my code/local/Abc/Catalog/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite><product_abstract>Abc_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract</product_abstract></rewrite>
             </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here is my code/local/Abc/Catalog/Product/Abstract.php

```
include_once "Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php";

class Abc_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
  public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = array())
    {
       echo 'here'; exit;

       /*if ($product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($product)) {
            if (!isset($additional['_escape'])) {
                $additional['_escape'] = true;
            }
            if (!isset($additional['_query'])) {
                $additional['_query'] = array();
            }
            $additional['_query']['options'] = 'cart';

            return $this->getProductUrl($product, $additional);
        }*/
        return $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
    } 
}
```

But its doesn't work. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In Magento it is not possible to rewrite an Abstract block in the traditional way. Can't you rewrite the class that is extending the abstract one?

Comment: Don't know that. Thanks for saving my time!

Comment: Your welcome ... it is possible tho to create a Mage folder under your local folder ... create exact same directory and place a copy of the Abstract class file there and then modify it. This however is ill adviced by Magento since it would compromise any future version updates of your installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a same folder/file structure for that abstract class you wish to override.
i.e.: `/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php` and write that entire class exactly equal as the original (with all methods), and change what you need.

No additional .xml is required, only the file on the specified folder.
But remember: when upgrading Magento maybe you need to review this file.